# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass - Values are not null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a method that loops through some objects and if a certain attribute is true, adds to the cost of the lesson to the money received, but keep getting the error undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass.

Here is the piece of code (the line producing the error start @activity.update_attribute):

```
def show

 @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
 @participants = Participant.all.where(:activity_id => @activity.id).map(&:user_id).uniq

 @all_participants = Participant.all.where(:activity_id => @activity.id)
 @all_participants.each do |a_participant|
  if a_participant.paid
    @activity.update_attribute(:money_received, @activity.money_received + @activity.cost)
  end
 end

 @users = Array.new
 @participants.each do |participant|
   @users.push(User.find(participant))
 end
end
```

And here is a screenshot from my database to show that neither is a null value:
[image]

Here is the error message that I get when running the application:[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: The database isn't null, but is the variable null? Try printing the variable by itself. I bet you'll find that it is, in fact, null. Also, which variable is supposedly null? You included the error but not the line reference

Comment: When I try to show the variable in an HTML ERB template, it does come out as null, but I can't understand why as I am calling the attribute the same as all the others (@activity.money_received), this is even before I try to add to it.

Comment: Show more of your code. Be sure to include controller code for the relevant var

Comment: where is your @activity object initiation?

Comment: Updated now to show all controller code

Comment: Can you also show the line number where the error happens and actual error stack as well?

Comment: Have added an image of the error in now

Comment: @Sion Roberts
Try to assign sum attributes to separate variable at line upper `update_attributes` method.
Try to inspect `@activity.money_received`, `@activity.cost` and `@activity` (call .inspect method for each of them.